# How to use div.appendChild(canvas) in p5JS?

Tags: javascript, canvas, p5.js

Hi have a simple script where I draw a circle in the middle of the canvas! What I want to do is to add the canvas at a specific point of the DOM.

Here is my code where I try to add the canvas inside the div with id `canvas` instead of where the script is!:

```js
function setup() {
  
  //REMOVE p5JS default canvas:
  //var p5Canvas = document.getElementById("defaultCanvas0");
  //p5Canvas.remove(); //Remove DOM element 

  //CREATE NEW CANVAS:
  //var canvas = createCanvas(400,400);
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.id = "myCanvas";
  canvas.width = "400";
  canvas.height = "400";
  var div = document.getElementById("test");
  div.appendChild(canvas);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  ellipse(width/2-25,height/2-25,50,50);
}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.2.0/p5.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>hello</h1>
    canvas goes here...
    
    <div id="test"></div>
    
    <br><br>
    after canvas
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

However if you run the above code you will find the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at setup (js:41)
    at p5._setup (p5.js:51363)
    at p5._start (p5.js:51286)
    at new p5 (p5.js:51639)
    at _globalInit (p5.js:50603)
```

Comment: You still need to create the canvas using something like:
document.createElement('canvas');
Not sure if create canvas makes a DOMElement object.

Comment: I just tried that! It ignores that and adds the canvas at the end of  the page! So I capture that as well and removed it (with id `defaultCanvas0`). Now I have to find a way to draw on new canvas that exists in the right div! Not sure why it stopped working and has a blank canvas instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the p5js docs and found out how to do it. Look at setup for the changes.

```js
function setup() {
  const canvas = createCanvas(400, 400);
  canvas.parent("test")
  canvas.style("display", "block")
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  ellipse(width / 2 - 25, height / 2 - 25, 50, 50);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.2.0/p5.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

</head>

<body>
  <h1>hello</h1>
  canvas goes here...

  <div id="test"></div>

  <br><br> after canvas
  <script src="sketch.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```